# Facebook Account Kit show in ionic popup

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I made FB account Kit login with sms and it works fine. But when I run it on device the popup with phone number entery wont show up. When I test it in browser it works fine and the pop up is opened but on mobile it wont open.
**My function is here:**

```
$scope.loginWithSMS = function($ionicPopup) {



      AccountKit.login("PHONE",{}, loginCallback);

      function loginCallback(response) {
              console.log(response);
              if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
                document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
                document.getElementById("csrf_nonce").value = response.state;
                document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
              }
              else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {

              }
              else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {

              }
            }
      }
    $scope.submit = function(){
        $scope.data = {};
        $http.post(app4travel.apiUrl + '/register_mobile')
          .success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            console.warn('Sent')
            console.warn(response)
            console.warn(status)
            $scope.response = response.data;
        })
    }
```

Comment: try to inspect your device and check for errors in console

Comment: I dont understan? when i test it in browser the popup is opened on button click but when i put it on phone test nothing change and popup doesn't show? @SaEChowdary

Comment: on phone means how your loading??like apk file or like a website?

Comment: I run like website. On mobile I use ionic View app where I put my app and test it, everything work except opening popup for fb account kit @SaEChowdary

Comment: conncet your mobile to pc and open your chrome browser and paste chrome://inspect in url you can inspect your mobile here and make sure you have installed proper usb software to detect your mobile

Comment: I tested and its work when i run my app threw browser but when I run as apk or ionic view there is no error but it wont still open facebook popup for login @SaEChowdary

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your browser's site settings. By default, browser doesn't allow popups so you need to enable it from settings.

In Chrome,

1. Go to Settings.
2. Select Site Settings.
3. Go to Popups and Redirects.
4. Allow popups

Check if your website is blocked and unblock it if it is blocked.